# Адаптация PHP регулярного выражения проверки телефона для JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть рабочее регулярное выражение на PHP `/^(380|\\+380)\d{9}$/`

Как написать тоже самое только на JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что символ `+` является [служебным символом регулярных выражений](http://developer.roman.grinyov.name/blog/17); поэтому, чтобы использовать его в качестве обычного символа, его нужно проэкранировать обратным слешем (`\`):

```
/^(380|\+380)\d{9}$/
```

Проверим ...

---

1. Сначала просто с помощью атрибута `pattern` ...

HTML:

```
<form action="//google.com/search" target="_blank">
  <input name="q" required pattern="(380|\+380)\d{9}">
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```

Работает: https://jsfiddle.net/q8wt17y3/

---

2. Теперь, для надёжности, и через JavaScript ...

HTML:

```
<form action="//google.com/search" target="_blank">
  <input name="q">
  <button>GO</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () {

  if ( !this.q.value.match( /^(380|\+380)\d{9}$/ ) ) {

    alert('No match with pattern!');

    return false;

  }

};
```

Работает: https://jsfiddle.net/4cfko1gq/

---

К слову, в HTML-атрибуте `pattern` обозначение начала (`^`) и конца данных (`$`) можно опускать, так как они заданы по умолчанию. А вот в Javascript они нужны, если вы конечно хотите обозначить начало и/или конец данных.

---

Также отмечу, что если вы создаёте регулярное выражение с помощью конструктора `new RegExp()`, то вместо одного обратного слеша (`\`) нужно указывать **два** (`\\`).

Дело в том, что конструктор `new RegExp()` принимает в качестве первого параметра обычную строку; а чтобы поместить в строку обратный слеш, его нужно проэкранировать; это связано с тем, что когда интерпретатор находит в строке обратный слеш, то он думает, что это [экранированная последовательность](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B) (например, перевод строки — `\n`).

Comment: Что-то не отображается код, там где «GO»?.. Не пойму почему.

Comment: спасибо, надо было добавить "\\" перед "+", а у меня стоял "\"

Comment: @w3lifer написали в чат модераторам о проблеме.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра, если вы создаёте регулярное выражение с помощью конструктора `new RegExp()`, то в нём нужно ставить два обратных слеша вместо одного, так как он принимает обычную строку в качестве первого параметра.

Comment: спасибо огромное, работает: var reg = new RegExp("(380|\\+380)\\d{9}"); Я так понял, что ^ и $ в джава указывать не надо.

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра, **нет**: в регулярных выражениях JavaScript (если вы под «джава» имели в виду его; так как Java — это другой язык программирования) нужно ставить `^` и `$` если вы хотите обозначить начало и конец данных соответственно. Это в HTML-атрибуте `pattern` их можно не указывать, так как они там по умолчанию стоят.

Comment: да, под джавой я имел ввиду именно JavaScript, потому как вопрос был о создании сайта, и я знаю что такое Java (с неё у меня все и начиналось). Тогда правильно будет  var reg = new RegExp("^(380|\\+380)\\d{9}$");?

Comment: @ВиталийФесюра, да — правильно: https://jsfiddle.net/4cfko1gq/1/ .

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
var phone = "+380111122222";
res = phone.match( /^(380|\+380)\d{9}$/ );
console.log(res[0]);
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //^(380|\+380)d{9}$/i/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: У вас почему-то экранирование у + пропало и лишние границы регулярного выражения.

Comment: надр было просто добавить "\\"